# Is CoreCLR support System.Collection.Generic types?

Tags: c#, generics, collections, coreclr

I hope someone in CoreCLR team will be in Stacks. I am very excited with CoreCLR. I tried to compile with the command:

```
C:\coreclr-demo>csc /nostdlib /noconfig /r:packages\System.Runtime.4.0.20-beta-2
2703\lib\contract\System.Runtime.dll /r:packages\System.Console.4.0.0-beta-22703
\lib\contract\System.Console.dll /out:runtime\HelloWorld.exe HelloWorld.cs
```

It's work.
But if I change my code to have Collection (List,Stack...) object, it's will through error, somekind of `The type or namespace name 'Stack' could not be found`, although, I got this error everytime I try to using any namespace except `System`.
I think may be I missed a library reference in the **csc** command to System.Collection.Generic. But I don't know where to find it, and from [an post in CoreCLR github talk about Generic](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/1611), I think the `System.Collection.Generic` was removed from CoreCLR. So I want to ask: Is CoreCLR support `System.Collection.Generic`, and, if yes, how can I use it with my compiling?

Thankyou

Comment: You need to add reference to the non generic collection assembly. Meanwhile, .NET Core requires a .xproj with project.json for compilation in most cases. Use csc directly means it is more difficult to find the proper assembly references.

Comment: How can I do the reference? As I know, Nuget have two types of configuration file: packages.config and project.json (nuget 3). In CoreCLR tutorial, they used packages.config. Can I do the reference using this file instead of project.json?
If that is, there will be something like this in the config file:
<package id="System.Collection.Generic" version="4.0.0-beta-22703" />
But I don't know where to find the right version for it.

Answer (score 1):

- System.Collection**s**.Generic is supported in CoreCLR
- In order to compile in this new world you need to use `dnx` or `dotnet`
- I recommend that you follow [this intro](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/README.md) to understand how to create projects using the new project model and add references to the NuGet packages that you need.

Comment: Hi, in that intro, they use "dnu restore" and "dnx run" command to compile and run, is it same the way of "csc" command?